# xlst in wso2 in making proxy service

Tags: xml, xslt, soap, wso2

here is my soap and i want to make for this proxy service to send to my another endpoint. i make it with :

```html
<xslt key="example"></xslt>
```

but i cant write local entrie for this soap "Add In-lined XML Entry
    XML content (XSLT, Policy, WSDL, etc...) that is being shared as an entry within the ESB"

```html
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:isompwsdl">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:PersonInfoByEnp soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
         <enp xsi:type="xsd:string">4577160876000115</enp>
      </urn:PersonInfoByEnp>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Please clarify the question. I don't understand what you're asking, and I imagine others are having trouble too.

Comment: i want to make a proxy servise via wso2 esb. and there is a trouble with this. I cant write it. I need to send this soap message to wso2 proxy servise and then it goes to another endpoint. I have to write this wso2 esb proxy.  - a bridge beetween me and my another endpoind

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, I still don't understand your problem : there is a trouble, which one ? you can't write your proxy, why ? in your question, you say you can't write your local entry, why, what is the error ?

Comment: Add In-lined XML Entry
 XML content (XSLT, Policy, WSDL, etc...) that is being shared as an entry within the ESB ( and here i need to add a xslt for my soap i i cant do it. Or there is another way to do it?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add local entry you can refer [this documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Local+Registry+Entries). in here you can find, how you can add local entry.

Then you can use that use that local entry within proxy. You don't need xslt mediator for that. [XSLT mediator](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/XSLT+Mediator) will be helpful for XSLT transformations.

Sample Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
   name="SampleProxy"
   transports="https http"
   startOnLoad="true"
   trace="disable">
<description/>
<target>
  <inSequence>
     <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
        <format key="sample-le"/>
        <args/>
     </payloadFactory>
    </inSequence>
  </target>
</proxy>

<localEntry key="sample-le"><![CDATA[abcd]]><description/>
</localEntry>
```